# MSSQL: Backup data stored in a table

Tags: sql-server

I need to back up all the data stored in my table1 because after I pass the value to another table, I am dropping this table. Is there a way to put in my query where it automatically back up and save as CSV file? (This is one way I can think to back up my file.)

So far, this is my code:
SELECT * FROM dbo.AA_WC_RAW_DATA_FINAL INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

I am getting error on "INTO" part. Seems like this is a mysql code.

Comment: Aren’t you backing up the whole database anyway? While MySQL’s idea of a backup is a big text file with an insert statement for every row, SQL Server has a lot more power here. Set aside a backup that has this table in its current state, test that you can restore it and that you can access the data in the table, then put that backup somewhere safe. This will prove a lot more useful than a text file.

Comment: This database has many tables under it and I dont need it all. I only want to backup one table. I am using this table just to pass the data to another table. After all the process, It will be deleted. So for example, another data comes in, It will create this table, Pass the data to another table, Table deleted. I would like somewhere in the middle that I can back up the data before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. Assuming you want to do it in code, I would suggest SQLCMD or PowerShell. There is a great article on SQL Server Central that details several options: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. All i can see is regarding cmd lines. is there a way whenever I execute my queries, it will automatically back up in CSV or any files?

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you looking for some means of "backup" to happen when you issue a SELECT statement to SQL Server, all automagically? If so, I'm sorry, but there's no mechanism for that. If you mean something else, please elaborate.